# import Constants in Symfony2 Service Container with a yml file

Tags: symfony

I would like to import constant in the Symfony2 Service Container. There is a cookbook which explains how to do it: [link to cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html)

According to this cookbook, you can't import constant in a yml file.
However, it has not been modified for 3 month, and not updated when Symfony2 went live.

Does anybody know if it's possible to import constant with a yml file now ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you use the symfony standard edition, you can add parameters into the `app/config/parameters.ini` file.

If you *really* want to use a yaml file, you can do that:

```
parameters:
    my.parameter: foobar
```

and then, you will be able to access in a controller like this:

```
$this->container->getParameter('my.parameter');
```

Comment: Do you mean all variable declared in parameters.ini can be access by the getParameter method of the container ?

Comment: Exactly. These are parameters of the DIC.